# Limiting value of a Lebesgue Integral

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Here's the problem:

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f \in L^{\infty}(\mu)$ and suppose that $\left|\left| f\right|\right|_{\infty} \leq 1$. Prove that:

$$\lim_{p \to 0} \int_{X} |f|^p \ d\mu = \mu[\{x \in X: |f(x)| > 0\}]$$

I am a little stuck on this and could use a hint on how to move forward with what I have.

---

Proof:

Let $\left|\left| f\right|\right|_{\infty} = 0$. Then, $f = 0$ almost everywhere. So, the equality holds trivially. Now, let the norm be greater than $0$. Let the set whose measure is being taken be denoted by $A$. Then, we have:

$$\left|\int_{X} |f|^p \ d\mu - \int_{X} \chi_{A} \ d\mu\right| \leq \int_{X} | |f|^p-\chi_A | \ d\mu$$

Now, observe that:

$$\mu[\{x \in X| |f(x)| > \left|\left| f \right|\right|_{\infty}\}] = 0$$

So, now, let $B = \{x \in X| |f(x)| \leq \left|\left| f \right|\right|_{\infty}\}$. Then, we can just integrate over $B$ instead. Now, we see that:

$$\{x \in X: |f(x)| > 0\} = \{x \in X: 0 < |f(x)| \leq \left|\left| f \right| \right|_{\infty}\} \cup \{x \in X: |f(x)| > \left|\left| f \right|\right|_{\infty} \}$$

The set on the right of $\cup$ is of measure $0$ by definition. So, we can just replace $A$ with the set on the left of $\cup$.

At this point, I'm a little bit stuck and I could use a hint (you can give a proof as well but try to put it in spoilers so that I only reference it after trying to use the hint). I kind of know that I want to find some kind of bound on $|f|^p-\chi_A$ but I'm not entirely sure how to really do it.

**Edit:**

Let $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence that converges to $0$. Consider the sequence defined by:

$$u_n = |f|^{p_n}$$

The issue I have is that $\{p_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ doesn't have to be decreasing, yes? So, applying monotone convergence seems to not be possible. However, I think I might have an argument that uses dominated convergence instead. So, following the reasoning I gave earlier, it is actually enough to integrate over the set:

$$A = \{x \in X: 0 < |f(x)| \leq \left|\left| f \right| \right|_{\infty} \}$$

because integration over the complement of the set will just yield $0$. Next, observe that for every $x \in A$, we have:

$$|u_n(x)| = |f(x)|^{p_n} \leq 1$$

and certainly, $1$ is Lebesgue Integrable. Finally, $u_n(x) \to 1$ pointwise for $x \in A$. Hence, by dominated convergence, we can see that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A} |f|^{p_n} \ d\mu = \int_{A} \lim_{n \to \infty} u_n(x) \ d\mu = \int_{A} 1 \ d\mu = \mu(A)$$

as was desired. Is this correct?

Comment: $\lim_{p\to 0^+}f(p)=\ell$ if and only if for all $(p_n)\in [0,\infty )^{\mathbb N}$ decreasing and converges to $0$, $\lim_{n\to \infty }f(p_n)=\ell$. So, you can take $(p_n)$ decreasing. Your proof is not correct because you can't use Dominated Convergence Theorem a priori (unless if $X$ is $\mu-$finite).

Comment: By $\mu$-finite, you mean that $\mu(X) < \infty$? I forgot to mention that the original question did say that $\mu$ is a finite measure. So, would my proof work in that case? I see why your proof works now, thanks :D

Comment: X being $\mu-$finite indeed mean that $\mu(X)<\infty $. And if $X$ is $\mu-$finite, then indeed your proof is correct (notice that you can define $A$ being $\{x\in X\mid |f(x)|>0\}$... no need to take $|f|\leq \|f\|_\infty $ since it holds a.e.)

Comment: Alright thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(p_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of positive numbers that converges to 0. Since $\|f\|_{L^\infty }\leq 1$, the sequence defined by $u_n:=|f|^{p_n}$ is increasing and positive. Your statement follows from Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Oh my god, that's so simple

Comment: Uh yea sorry, I am still not quite getting this but let me write things down and I'll come back to you with more questions in a bit.

Comment: I have edited my post with a proposed solution based off of your idea, could you have a look and let me know if that works?